# N-variate normal Distribution Problem

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Suppose $(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ is a normal random vector with mean $u=(u_1,\cdots,u_n)$ and covariance matrix $S$. Define random variable $Y$ as $Y=X_1+\cdots+X_n$.

1) Find mean and variance of $Y$.

2) Find pdf of $Y$.

This is the first time I have seen this kind of distribution. Would the mean of $Y$ be $=u_1+u_2+\cdots+u_n$? and variance be $=var(X_1)+var(X_2)+\cdots+var(X_n)*2$ covariance matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For r.v.'s with finite means $$E(X_1+\ldots+X_n)=EX_1+\ldots+EX_n,$$
and for finite variances
$$Var(X_1+\ldots+X_n)=Var(X_1)+\ldots+Var(X_n)+2\sum_{i<j} S_{i,j},$$
where $S_{i,j}$ is covariance of $X_i$ and $X_j$. If we note that $Var(X_i)=S_{i,i}$ and $S_{i,j}=S_{j,i}$, the variance  is converted into
$$Var(X_1+\ldots+X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n S_{i,j}.$$

See [variance of sum of correlated variables here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables).